# how can i do a server automatically in c#

Tags: c#, client-server

I have already done a manual server-client connection in windows form c #, I used buttons to do the server creation and the client connection with the server.
But now I want it when starting the server application that automatically creates the server
I already tried the commands to create the server in form load but it did not work
Do you have any idea how to do it?

client https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpNuV.jpg
server https://i.stack.imgur.com/el57w.jpg

Comment: Your question is very mysterious, please provide some code of how your application works

Comment: link with the code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question in its current form is not a good fit for Stack Overflow and cannot be answered within the scope of this site. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to run Server connection in one thread and Client Connection in another thread

Create 2 methods for client and server connection and start them in separate thread

```
Thread t = New Thread(Your_Method)
```

note that you cannot access GUI elements directly from another thread [See this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx) for accessing GUI elements from thread

Comment: have you reached your goal..?